# Partitioning by date?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are experimenting with BigQuery to analyze user data generated by our software application.

Our working table consists hundreds of millions of rows, each representing a unique user "session". Each containing a timestamp, UUID, and other fields describing the user's interaction with our product during that session. We currently generate about 2GB of data (~10M rows) per day.

Every so often we may run queries against the entire dataset (about 2 months worth right now, and growing), However typical queries will span just a single day, week, or month. We're finding out that as our table grows, our single-day query becomes more and more expensive (as we would expect given BigQuery architecture)

What isthe best way to query subsets of of our data more efficiently? One approach I can think of is to "partition" the data into separate tables by day (or week, month, etc.) then query them together in a union:

`SELECT foo from
mytable_2012-09-01,
mytable_2012-09-02,
mytable_2012-09-03;`

Is there a better way than this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi David: The best way to handle this is to shard your data across many tables and run queries as you suggest in your example.

To be more clear, BigQuery does not have a concept of indexes (by design), so sharding data into separate tables is a useful strategy for keeping queries as economically efficient as possible.

On the flip side, another useful feature for people worried about having too many tables is to set an [expirationTime](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource) for tables, after which tables will be deleted and their storage reclaimed - otherwise they will persist indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. Are there any plans to introduce better sharding support in the future? using this method I can see our queries  quite long (e.g. running a query over 1 year on a dataset sharded by day.) Could be a problem given the 10k query size limit (?)

Comment: Yes - because of the situation you just mentioned, we are looking into improving the ability to refer to multiple tables (using a single pattern) in queries, but unfortunately we don't yet have such a feature available at the moment. By the way, the first place we usually mention new feature updates is on the (low-volume) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-announce mailing list, so I suggest subscribing.

Comment: @DavidMSmith What did you go for finally?

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery now supports table partitions by date:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x