# How to make tables optional in a Bigquery Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a set of sharded data similar to "[Partitioning by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433322/partitioning-by-date)" but some days do not have data and hence no days.  An ideal solution would be to make all tables (dates) optional.  Is that possible?

In detail: If you do a select from followed by a sequence [main.2013-08-01], [main.2013-08-02], ... every table must exist. If any of those tables do not exist, bigquery responds with a 500 error when attempting to execute the query. By using the term "optional" I am hoping for a syntax that would allow any particular table not to exist, but the query to still execute against the other tables in sum.  An example of what I am hoping for: perhaps the query says SELECT * from ?[main.2013-08-01], ?[main.2013-08-02], ...  but [main.2013-08-02] does not exist.  Howevever, because it has the "?" indicator before the table it is considered optional and the query still executes successfully, and I get results, though only from [main.2013-08-01] and any other tables that actually do exist.

I am currently solving this problem by first doing a request for a dataset's table list and then comparing against the shards that I actually want to query for existence and merging the tables (e.g. I want all days in August, bigquery tells me that 7/27 doesn't exist, so my FROM block will contain a list of all data shards EXCEPT 7/27), but this method is complicated and involves two bigquery round trips, so it does not seem ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by making tables optional.

Comment: I edited the question with more details that will hopefully clear it up!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, have you tried having empty tables?

Let's say main.2013-08-01 exists, and main.2013-08-02 does not. You could:

```
SELECT * FROM [main.2013-08-01] WHERE any_column = 'non existing value'
```

That query will return 0 results, and you can select main.2013-08-02 as the destination table. This will create an empty table, with the same columns as main.2013-08-01. Then you can join without caring about emptiness!

Comment: Thanks Fh, I suspect that would work as a workaround, but only if I knew in advance which tables were missing.  In order to find which tables were missing, I would have to do something like my existing dataset table list query against all possible month-days and then add an additional step on top of that to execute the query that you suggest followed by my final query that I actually use to process the data.  So in this particular case, this method is actually slower than the workaround I am currently using.