# Partitioning based on column data?

Tags: google-bigquery

When creating a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) using `bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY` are the partitions created based on the **load time** of the data, not a date key within the table data itself?

To create partitions based on dates within the date, is the current approach to manually create sharded tables, and load them based on date, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433322/partitioning-by-date) from 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, partitions created based on data load time not based on data itself
You can use partition decorator (`mydataset.mytable1$20160810`) if you want to load data into specific partition

Per my understanding, partition by column is something that we should expect to be supported at some point  - but not now

Comment: Adding a clarification -- the post from 2012 discusses creating sharded tables. You can load/append/copy to a specific partition of the table. So you'd have a single table but with multiple dated partitions:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#restating_data_in_a_partition

Comment: To confirm, I can create and populate new paritions simply using a table$YYYYMMDD destination based on my date column values?

Answer (score 3):

Good news, BigQuery currently supports 2 type data partition, included partition by column. Please check [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables).

I like the feature: An individual operation can commit data into up to 2,000 distinct partitions.

Comment: What do you mean saying "partition by column"?

Comment: You could check above link:
Partitioned tables: Tables that are partitioned based on a TIMESTAMP or DATE column.

Comment: 3 type data partition? I believe it is 2 type of partition, based on ingestion time or based on date type column.